# ReactGA BrowserRouter Uncaught TypeError: undefined (reading 'pathname') error and/or useLocation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, router

I try to install Google Analytics, but then my site won't load.

I had the error: `Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
So I added `<Routes>` to `index.js`

Index.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Router>
    <HelmetProvider>
      <App />
    </HelmetProvider>
  </Router>

);
```

My App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
import InitializeReactGA from "./components/helper/googleAnalytics";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

...

const TRACKING_ID = "A-1234567890"
ReactGA.initialize(TRACKING_ID );

function usePageViews() {
    let location = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        InitializeReactGA(ReactGA);
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
    }, [location]);

function App() {
  usePageViews();

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/"                            element={<Home                          />} />
          <Route path="/abouts"                      element={<AboutUs                       />} />
          .....
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    
    </>
  );
}
```

GA helper:

```js
function InitializeReactGA(ReactGA) {
  if (!window.GA_INITIALIZED) {
    ReactGA.initialize("MANDO_GA");  //just copied that, don't know what MANDO_GA is
    window.GA_INITIALIZED = true;
  }
}

export default InitializeReactGA;
```

now I get the error:
`components.tsx:197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`

Comment: i think u need to import it - `import { useLocation } from 'idk'` from 'react', or from where?

Comment: import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom"; is imported

Comment: you need to use the usePageViews() inside the router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried some stuff because of @Miguel Caro

index.js:

```js
<Router>
    <HelmetProvider>
      <App />
    </HelmetProvider>
  </Router>
```

App.js:

```js
function App() {
  usePageViews();

  return (
    <>
       {/* DELETED!  Router  DELETED! */}
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/"                            element={<Home                          />} />
          <Route path="/abouts"                      element={<AboutUs                       />} />
          .....
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      {/* DELETED! /Router  DELETED!*/}
    
    </>
  );
}
```

now it works

Answer (score 1):

that happen when you use the useLocation outside of the router